# Laravel livewire How to use if , else condition on array value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

laravel livewire I'm trying using if, else condition for foreach loop, but I'm Getting Error
help me to solve this

**Error**

```
Array to string conversion
```

**Controller**

```
public function Report() 
{
//this below $this->dateRange code gives full complete month date
$this->dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth())->toArray();

$this->StudentList = Student::get();
$data =  $this->StudentList->sortBy('date', SORT_NATURAL)->groupby('date');
$this->GroupDate = array_keys($data->toArray()); 

//$this->GroupDate *below code having*
// array:14 [▼   
//  "2024-01-01"  
//  "2024-01-02"  
//  "2024-01-03"  
//  "2024-01-04" 
//  "2024-01-05"  
//...
]

}
```

**Blade View**

```
<table class="datatable table">
  <thead> 
  @if(!empty($this->dateRange)) 
    <tr> 
  @foreach ($this->dateRange as $key=>$date) 
      <th>
        {{$date->format('d')}}
      </th> 
  @endforeach
    </tr> 
  @endif 
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
@if(!empty($this->GroupDate )) 
<tr> 
@foreach ($this->dateRange as $key=>$dateRanges) 
  @if($dateRanges->format('d-m-Y') == \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->GroupDate)->format('d-m-Y')) 
      <td> 
       1 
     </td> 
  @else 
      <td> 
       0 
     </td> 
  @endif 
  @endforeach 
</tr> 
 @endforeach 
    @endif 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

laravel livewire I'm trying using if, else condition for foreach loop, but I'm Getting Error help me to solve this

Comment: `$this->GroupDate` is an array (consider renaming it to GroupDates, so it is clear from the name that this is more than one date). You can't create a date from an array.

Comment: @brombeer where I have to use this GroupDates In controller Or Blade

Comment: Renaming it won't solve your problem, you'd need to loop over `$this->GroupDate` or use [in\_​array](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) to check if one date is contained in the array

Comment: @brombeer can you give any reference or example if possible correct my code

Comment: There is a reference in my comment, you just need to click it. To loop over an array you can use ... `@foreach` (as you already did). Good luck

Comment: @brombeer I tried but I'm getting same error "Array to string conversion"  @if(in_array($dateRanges->format('d-m-Y') == \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->GroupDate)->format('d-m-Y')))

Comment: That usage of `in_array` doesn't make sense and you are **still** trying to create a date from an array. That doesn't work (as already mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, it expects a string, But you're passing an array.

```
@if($dateRanges->format('d-m-Y') == \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->GroupDate)->format('d-m-Y'))
```

---

For that, you have to loop through `foreach` (or similar array iterations) in order to solve this.

```
<tbody> 
@if(!empty($this->GroupDate)) 
    <tr> 
    @foreach ($this->dateRange as $date) 
        @if(in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $this->GroupDate)) 
            <td>1</td> 
        @else 
            <td>0</td> 
        @endif 
    @endforeach 
    </tr> 
@endif
</tbody>
```